# Load Azure SQL database audit logs into Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure, audit, audit-logging

My preferred location to review database audit logs is in a database, an Azure database to be specific. To be even more specific, I would like to review my Azure database audit logs for my Azure database in that same Azure database. How do I automate this?

#### What has worked so far?

In Azure SQL database, under "Auditing", set the destination to Storage. Audit logs will accumulate in your Storage account. Next, in the Azure Portal, go to your storage account. Go to the container with the audit file(s). In "Manage ACL", "Add Principal" > Users > Add your user. Give them permissions (e.g., read, write, execute). Click "Save" at the bottom.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file('https://{Azure storage account}.blob.core.windows.net/{container}/{...path to file...}/{audit file name}.xel',null, null);
```

The default Azure database auditing appears to create audit files with random names. To automatically upload the files, I will likely need an Azure function to iterate through the blob directory to find the file name and move it into the database. The procedure above could then load the audit file into the database.

#### What have I tried?

The Microsoft database audit log reference does not list a database option: [Set up Auditing for Azure SQL Database and Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auditing-setup?view=azuresql-db)

This SO question suggests a way to import blob storage into a SQL database: [Automation to Read SQL Database Audit Logs in Azure](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/loading-files-from-azure-blob-storage-into-azure-sql-database/ba-p/386133). Is this the way?

Azure Active Directory audit logs have an API: [Prerequisites to access the Azure Active Directory reporting API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-configure-prerequisites-for-reporting-api)

Microsoft has a special SQL function for loading audit logs: sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file. Getting warmer? [Import Extended Events XEL File?](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/import-extended-events-xel-file), [EXTENDED EVENTS DATA](https://www.scarydba.com/2011/10/17/extended-events-data/), [Microsoft function docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-xe-file-target-read-file-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

##### Most promising, but not working

Connecting SQL with Azure: [Transact-SQL code that uses Azure Storage container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/xevent-code-event-file?view=azuresql-mi#phase-2-transact-sql-code-that-uses-azure-storage-container)

---

#### Tangent: Keeping the data on the database instead of loading files

Question: If these audit events are produced by the database, they must have some type of memory footprint. Why can't I access this memory and forget about trying to load a file in the database?

Answer: While the database does produce the events, it seems the events are stored in a buffer that does not/cannot write to a database table. (Perhaps writing to a database table reduced database performance.) Therefore, I cannot readily access the audit logs produced by Azure prior to their writing to blob.

[Targets for your Azure SQL Database event sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/xevent-db-diff-from-svr?view=azuresql-mi#targets-for-your-azure-sql-database-event-sessions)

While it may be possible to re-create the Azure audit logging with session monitoring, it seems overly difficult. For example, the Azure audit logs are broken into daily files likely starting/stopping the auditing session. The audit also captures specific events, which I would need to figure out what to include/not include. But, these views appear to be where the data is stored in a tabular format.

[New dynamic management views (DMVs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/xevent-db-diff-from-svr?view=azuresql-mi#new-dynamic-management-views-dmvs)

Learning about "Extended events": [Extended events in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/xevent-db-diff-from-svr?view=azuresql-mi)

The Azure database auditing produces a .xel ("Extended Events") file. This file is binary and cannot be easily read without Microsoft tools (e.g., not notepad). The file is also XML, likely because each event has different fields, making it non-relational and difficult to load in a database.
[Extended Events overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-ver16)

Maybe Azure uses these events for auditing. [SQL Server Event Class Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/security-audit-event-category-sql-server-profiler?view=azuresqldb-current)

---

Comment: What is the format of the files written to Blob Storage? Is it CSV? If so [technically you could probably use `OPENROWSET` to read them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-ver16) though I doubt it will be a particularly enjoyable experience - as AFAIK things like wildcards in the file path aren't yet supported there (despite being available in Synapse Serverless flavour)

Comment: Perhaps reconsider your resistance to newer technologies. Have you taken a look at KQL (the language used to query Azure logs) ? I have used SQL for many years and to my mind it is the bedrock of data, but KQL improves on it substantially. Keep in mind it seems like you're doing a bunch of data engineering work here to avoid learning about new tech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My preferred location to review database audit logs is in a database, an Azure database to be specific.

**AFAIK there is no direct way to load Audit file in to Azure SQL .**

**You can try two workaround:**

1. You can try first creating view on the audit file by Selecting rows from `sys.fn_get_audit_file` and then you can create table based on this view using **SELECT INTO**.

```sql
--creating view
CREATE VIEW View1 AS SELECT * FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file('https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/sqldbauditlogs/ShiraServer/MayaDB/SqlDbAuditing_Audit/2017-07-14/10_45_22_173_1.xel', DEFAULT, DEFAULT); GO

--Loading view into table
SELECT * INTO New_Table FROM view1;
```

2. Using [Merge audit files in SQL Server Management Studio](https://www.sqlshack.com/getting-started-with-azure-sql-database-auditing-using-blob-storage/) convert the audit files into CSV format then load that CSV file to blob storage and then read it.

- First Connect to SQL server n from the menu choose **File >> Open >> Merge Audit Files**:
  [image: this is an image description]
- The next step will require to define the path for merging audit. you can select Blob storage here and connect appropriate storage account and container and click on ok:
  [image]
- To export the data, choose **Extended Events >> Export to >> CSV** and load this CSV file to blob storage and as Martin Smith said you can read the data from Blob storage with CSV type using [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-ver16).